# wrong allocate memory matrix C?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm developing a program that read from CSV file and calculate score with a method "calculateMLpa". The method receive array of char and array of 10 float, and transform array of float in matrix 3x3. When read the position 3rd number from array, insert in matrix the 4th number and same for 6th number.
I.E.

```
array value[]={0.000000;123.814934;234.000000;100.000000;166.000000; 203.086639;383.000000;186.000000;338.000000;173.098419 }
array traj[]={"0-0";"0-1";"0-2";"1-0";"1-1";"1-2";"2-0";"2-1";"2-2"}
Xn_val[]={"0","1","2"}
```

When transform in matrix the result is:

```
123.814934 234.000000 166.000000 
166.000000 203.086639 186.000000 
186.000000 338.000000 173.098419
```

While the expected for [0;2] is 100.000000 and for [1;2]=383.000000, but when print the currently value of traj it's correct.
How can I fix this problem?

The code is all here:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
int csv_parse ( char *line, int size )
{
    char *p;
    char *dp;
    int inquote;
    int na;
    int nTo_comma;
    char prevc = ',';
    char *list[256];

    dp = NULL;
    // inquote = 0;
    na = 0;
    prevc = ';';

    nTo_comma=0;
    for ( p = line; *p != '\n'; p++ )
    {
        nTo_comma++;
        list[nTo_comma] = p;
        if(*p == prevc)
        {
            printf("%s\t", list);

            return na;
        }

    }

    printf("\n");

    return na;
}


double calculateMLpa(const char *Xn_val[], char *traj[], float value[], double alphaxixj, double tauxi, int sz, int dim) {
    double mlx = 0;
    double v;
    double alphaxi;
    char *state;
    int i;
    int p;
    int j;
    int k;
//  int sz = sizeof(Xn_val) / sizeof(int);
//  int dim = sizeof(traj) / sizeof(char);
    double trns[sz][sz];
    double m[sz];
    char *trat="-";



    // m[xi] values: the number of transitions leaving the state xi
    printf("%d %d \n",sz,dim);
    int cont=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= sz; i++) {
        m[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j <= sz; j++) {
            v = 0.0;
            int newlength = strlen(Xn_val[i])+strlen(trat)+strlen(Xn_val[j])+1;
            state = malloc(sizeof(char)*newlength);
            if(state != NULL){
                state[0] = '\0';
                strcat(state,Xn_val[i]);
                strcat(state,trat);
                strcat(state,Xn_val[j]);
                printf("%s ",state);
            }else {
                printf(stderr,"malloc failed!\n");
            }
            //          for (k=0; k<=dim;++k){
            if (traj[cont] != NULL ){
                if (strcmp(traj[cont],state)==0){
                    v = value[cont+1];
                    printf("%f \n",v);
                }
            }

            trns[i][j] = v;

            printf("%f - \n",trns[i][j]);
            if (strcmp(Xn_val[i],Xn_val[j])!=0)
                m[i] = m[i] + v;

            cont++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<=sz;++i){
        for(j=0;j<=sz;++j){

            printf("%f ",trns[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    for (p=0;p<=sz;++p){
        printf("%f - \n",m[p]);
    }
    printf("%f %f\n",trns[0][1],trns[0][2]);
    alphaxi = alphaxixj * (((double) sz) - 1.0);
    alphaxi = alphaxixj;
    printf("%d ",sz);
    for (i = 0; i <= sz; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= sz; j++) {
            // xi!=xj
            if (strcmp(Xn_val[i], Xn_val[j])!=0) {
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxixj + trns[i][j]) - lgamma(alphaxixj);
            }
            // xi
            else {
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi) - lgamma(alphaxi + m[i]);
                mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0)+ (alphaxi + 1.0) * log(tauxi);
                mlx = mlx - lgamma(alphaxi + 1.0)- (alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0) * log(tauxi + trns[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return (mlx);
}


#define MAXFLDS 200     /* maximum possible number of fields */
#define MAXFLDSIZE 32   /* longest possible field + 1 = 31 byte field */

void parse(char *record, char *delim, char arr[][MAXFLDSIZE], int *fldcnt) {
    char*p = strtok(record, delim);
    int fld = 0;
    while (p) {
        strcpy(arr[fld], p);
        fld++;
        p = strtok('\0', delim);
    }
    *fldcnt = fld;
}

void main() {
    printf("inizio\n");
    FILE *pf;
    int N=20;
    bool first=true;
    const char *a[]={"0","1","2"};
    char *traject[]={"0-0","0-1","0-2","1-0","1-1","1-2","2-0","2-1","2-2"};
    double bs=0;
    char *trat="-";


    pf=fopen("//home//user//prova.csv","r");

    float array[10][10];
    float *t;
    char *str= "hello";
    char *state;
    t = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    int f=0;
    if (pf)
    {

        size_t i, j, k;
        char buffer[BUFSIZ], *ptr;
        /*
         * Read each line from the file.
         */
        for ( i = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf); ++i )
        {
            /*
             * Parse the comma-separated values from each line into 'array'.
             */
            for ( j = 0, ptr = buffer; j < ARRAYSIZE(*array); ++j, ++ptr )
            {
                array[i][j] = strtof(ptr, &ptr);
            }
        }
        fclose(pf);}

    else /* fopen() returned NULL */
    {
        perror(pf);
    }

    for(f=0; f<10; ++f){
        if(f==0){}
        else if(f==1 && array[f][8]==0)
            array[f][8]=123.8149353;
        t[f]=array[f][8];
        //printf("%f \n",t[f]);
    }
    for (f=0;f<10; ++f){
        printf("%f - ",t[f]);
    }
    //printf("%s, %s, %s \n",a[0],a[1],a[2]);

    printf("start\n");
    int sz = sizeof(a) / sizeof(char);
    int dim = sizeof(traject) / sizeof(char);
    printf("%d , %d \n",sz,dim);
    bs=calculateMLpa(a,traject,t,1.0,0.1,sz,dim);
    printf("done \n");
    printf("%f ",bs);


}
```

EDIT
I try to pass array size

```
sz=sizeof(a)/sizeof(char) 
dim = sizeof(traject) / sizeof(char);
```

but their value is 24 and 72 respectively, and the execution stops at 0-2 value 100.000000

Comment: Since you have `ARRAYSIZE` why do you then use `sizeof(<char*[] variable>)/sizeof(int)`? `sizeof(int)` **is not** necessarily the same as `sizeof(char*)`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays passed to functions decay to pointers to the start of the array. So

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
```

Will not return anything meaningful when checking for its size in that case

To fix, pass the Array size as an additional Argument.

Answer (score 2):

One major problem is that when you pass arrays to functions, they decay to *pointers*, and the `sizeof` trick you use to get the array size will not work.

You need to pass the actual array sizes as arguments.